# Android Studio - emulator killed

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run the emulator on Android Studios it proceeds about halfway down before a pop up window launches. I realize this has been asked before but I have tried the solutions found in those threads and none of them have worked so far. Have tons of space on the computer.

So far from scouring stackoverflow I have tried

1. Enabling Virtualization tech in the BIOS
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling the emulator through the SDK manager
3. Wiping and cold running the previously created devices.
4. Downloading a different system image using a different version of Android and running that
5. Externally downloading HAXM
6. Redownloading it interanally

Is there anything I'm missing or haven't tried, maybe trying a different platform in the settings or maybe I'm missing something that could be going wrong on a hardware level?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Android Studio 4.2 update had brought plenty errors .The above methods you tried are absolute correct .Just give try to this method
Go To  Help -> Check for Updates... and chose "Update All" to update everything in the list.
Please don't forget to restart Android Studio IDE
Hope this may help :)
Edit: If the above method doesn't work change system image file of emulator to Android 9 (Pie)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I have also face the same issue.
But Later I found an issue in my os (Windows 7) then I updated my Windows and the Issue has been resolved.